# ¿Cómo unir dos documentos de mongodb?

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, data, nosql, mongod

quisiera saber si alguien puede ayudarme con esto, estoy intentando mandar a llamar el contenido de un documento usando su id en Mongodb, algo así como si fueran bases de datos relacionales.

Tengo la colección REPORTE, la cual en su campo "history" hace referencia con el ObjectId a la colección DATA como muestro a continuación:

**DATA**

```
 {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "611be666a0139450ac394e988"
    },
    "descripcion": "Dato de origen",
  }
```

**REPORTE**

```
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61941f92cd62d204d11372"
    },
    "year": 2021,
    "month": "FEB",
    "client": {
      "title": "REFACCIONES"
    },
    "history": [
      {
        "data": {
          "$oid": "611be666a0139450ac394e988"
        },
        "countrys": [
          {
            "country": "MEX",
            "value": "2"
          },
          {
            "country": "BRA",
            "value": "2"
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

El problema surge cuando intento consultar ambas colecciones ya que trato de hacer que haga match el ObjectId del campo history en el reporte con el ObjectId del la colección DATA. Para que me devuelva algo como esto:

```
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61941f92cd62d204d11372"
    },
    "year": 2021,
    "month": "FEB",
    "client": {
      "title": "REFACCIONES"
    },
    "history": [
      {
        "data": {
          "$oid": "611be666a0139450ac394e988",
          "descripcion": "Dato de origen",
        },
        "countrys": [
          {
            "country": "MEX",
            "value": "2"
          },
          {
            "country": "BRA",
            "value": "2"
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo podría conectarlas?. Estoy usando esta consulta con un **$lookup**:

```
{
  from: 'data',
  'let': {
    id: '$_id'
  },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: [
            '$history.data',
            '$$id'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        descripcion: 1,
        'history.countrys': 1
      }
    }
  ],
  as: 'result.data'
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En mis consultas procuro utilizar una referencia y con este tipo de búsqueda anido o "relaciono" las colecciones según el parámetro de unión.

```
{
   $lookup: {
   from: 'coleccion-padre',
   localField: 'coleccion-padre-id',
   foreignField: 'identificador-entre-colecciones',
   as: 'asi-llamo-el-objeto-resultado',
  },
},
```

Un ejemplo en producción sería algo como esto

```
.aggregate([
          //Obviar de la consulta el campo password
          { $project: { password: 0 } },
          //Validar si el campo existe según los parámetros pasados
          {
            $match: {
              warehouseId: { $exists: true, $ne: '' },
              status: true,
            },
          },
          //Agregamos los campos que van a ser relacionados en un objectId
          {
            $addFields: {
              warehouseId: {
                $toObjectId: '$warehouseId',
              },
            },
          },
          //Búsqueda relacionada entre dos colecciones
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'points-sale',
              localField: 'warehouseId',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'warehouse',
            },
          },
        ])
```